# fabricjs - Zoom canvas in viewport (possible?)

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, fabricjs

at the moment I try to implement a **zoom-functionallity** to a visual-editor based on the [fabricjs-framework](http://fabricjs.com).

I've looked around but got more and more confused as I recognized that the development of this feature/function was a long and rocky road for the community and developers.

Because of that, many solutions seems to be already outdated.

But at the moment I found [**fabric-viewport** developed by the **RTSGroup** on Github](https://github.com/rstgroup/fabricjs-viewport).

The implementation was easy, but it only can zoom/control the objects in (inner of) the canvas. Not the canvas too. But I would like to zoom the canvas, too. (inner of the viewport)

For better understanding what I'm looking for I made a simple explanation-image:

[image: Example]

Is there a way to do this with the fabricjs-viewport plugin or another not outdated solution?

I saw already some pages who using such viewport like zoom feature with scroll support, too. But there I wasn't sure if they belong to the **fabricjs-framework**.

Thanks already for every hint and tipp which could lead me to the right direction.

Greetings, 
Sascha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can create zoomIn & zoomOut functionality with the feabricjs **either on the objects that they are on the canvas and ,also, on the canvas itself**

in order to **zoomIn and zoomOut** the canvas itself , **you should** change its **height** and  **width** parametes, into the zoomIn/zoomOut functions, so when it goes to change the objects, it will also **change the canvas size**:

**for zoomIn**:

```
   canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
   canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);
```

**for zoomOut**:

```
canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR));
canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR));
```

please take a look on the live fiddle example that i made , which it zoomsIn and Out objects and canvas, the .

live fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/39up3jcm/

hope helps, 
good luck

Answer (score 12):

@Theo solution is great, but one thing:
Instead of using `object.scaleX` and `object.scaleY` to scale each object in the canvas, you can just call once to `canvas.setZoom(ZOOM_INDEX)`.
(only from version 1.4.13 of fabricjs)

An example I made is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dudih/y0z33gym/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: Nice, thank you for the share! It seems I've to update our code.

Comment: how to change canvas size when zoomed in relative to the scale factor?

Comment: Not an answer. It was a question of zooming the canvas with elements inside, not just elements.