# Fabric.js: cannot get bounding box to match it's (dynamic) object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to give the user of a page the possibility to draw his/her own polygon onto an image. I use fabric.js (1.5.0) for that, and I borrowed quite some code from the examples there, however, in my case, the bounding boxes of the created polygons just don't match the polygons.
FireBug shows the points of the polygons being rather local than global, what is in my believe the cause of the problem. I'm kind of lost though in finding the crucial lines...

```
See the jsfiddle below for my example
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y9kqjLhk/

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

i hade the same issue a few months ago, as i wanted to draw a dynamic polygon with mouse click.
i give you an example on jsfiddle that you can do exactly what you need, the only difference is that i use the previous version of fabricjs .
i hope it helps, good luck.

this is the code and below i give the live jsfiddle example:

```
var roof = null;
var roofPoints = [];
var lines = [];
var lineCounter = 0;
var drawingObject = {};
drawingObject.type = "";
drawingObject.background = "";
drawingObject.border = "";

function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}


$("#btnRoof").click(function () {
    if (drawingObject.type == "roof") {
        drawingObject.type = "";
        lines.forEach(function(value, index, ar){
             canvas.remove(value);
        });
        //canvas.remove(lines[lineCounter - 1]);
        roof = makeRoof(roofPoints);
        canvas.add(roof);
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
        drawingObject.type = "roof"; // roof type
    }
});


// canvas Drawing
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas',{backgroundColor : 'yellow'});
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

fabric.util.addListener(window,'dblclick', function(){ 
        drawingObject.type = "";
        lines.forEach(function(value, index, ar){
             canvas.remove(value);
        });
        //canvas.remove(lines[lineCounter - 1]);
        roof = makeRoof(roofPoints);
        canvas.add(roof);
        canvas.renderAll();

    console.log("double click");
    //clear arrays
     roofPoints = [];
     lines = [];
     lineCounter = 0;

});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
    if (drawingObject.type == "roof") {
        canvas.selection = false;
        setStartingPoint(options); // set x,y
        roofPoints.push(new Point(x, y));
        var points = [x, y, x, y];
        lines.push(new fabric.Line(points, {
            strokeWidth: 1,
            selectable: false,
            stroke: 'red'
        }).setOriginX(x).setOriginY(y));
        canvas.add(lines[lineCounter]);
        lineCounter++;
        canvas.on('mouse:up', function (options) {
            canvas.selection = true;
        });
    }
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function (options) {
    if (lines[0] !== null && lines[0] !== undefined && drawingObject.type == "roof") {
        setStartingPoint(options);
        lines[lineCounter - 1].set({
            x2: x,
            y2: y
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});

function setStartingPoint(options) {
    var offset = $('#canvas').offset();
    x = options.e.pageX - offset.left;
    y = options.e.pageY - offset.top;
}

function makeRoof(roofPoints) {

    var left = findLeftPaddingForRoof(roofPoints);
    var top = findTopPaddingForRoof(roofPoints);
    roofPoints.push(new Point(roofPoints[0].x,roofPoints[0].y))
    var roof = new fabric.Polyline(roofPoints, {
    fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    stroke:'#7F7F7F'
    });
    roof.set({

        left: left,
        top: top,

    });


    return roof;
}

function findTopPaddingForRoof(roofPoints) {
    var result = 999999;
    for (var f = 0; f < lineCounter; f++) {
        if (roofPoints[f].y < result) {
            result = roofPoints[f].y;
        }
    }
    return Math.abs(result);
}

function findLeftPaddingForRoof(roofPoints) {
    var result = 999999;
    for (var i = 0; i < lineCounter; i++) {
        if (roofPoints[i].x < result) {
            result = roofPoints[i].x;
        }
    }
    return Math.abs(result);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/svb3q6xL/1/

*click on the label to start drawind and stop drawing on mouse double click, enywhere on canvas.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps a lot! In fact it  almost solved my problem!
However, with Fabric.js 1.4.0 I need to find an alternative to the "setZoom" and "getZoom" method. I wonder why the two versions behave in such a different way, though...

Comment: hello, i dont know either,  why the newer version ,1.5 ,behaves in different way, but it's ok as long as it helped you with your issue. 
as for the zoom functionality i have answered on another post (zoomIn & zoomOut ) with a live jsfiddle example, 
You could take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732710/fabricjs-zoom-canvas-in-viewport-possible/30750227#30750227